# How to declare variables of a slot to another slot

Tags: qt, global-variables, slot

I have a problem to get acsess to variable from slot to another slot. For example in bellow code, i getting an Error:

> "img" was not declared in this scope

My code:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushload_clicked()
{
    QString url = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Load Color Image File"), QString(),
                                                 tr("*.jpg ;*.png ;*.jpeg ;;All Files (*)"));

    QPixmap img(url);
}


void MainWindow::on_pushprocess_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setPixmap(img);
    ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: Better to set this variable - img as a local, and pass its by reference to another method

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` variable is a local variable and you can't access it anywhere else, unless you define it as `Global variable` or a member variable of your `MainWindow` class.

pseudocode:

```
class MainWindow {
public:
...

private:
QPixmap img{};
}
```

Your Slots:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushload_clicked()
{
    QString url = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Load Color Image File"), QString(),
                                                 tr("*.jpg ;*.png ;*.jpeg ;;All Files (*)"));

    QPixmap temp_img(url);
    img = temp_img;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushprocess_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setPixmap(img);
    ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

Comment: I would strongly discourage from telling beginners about global variables... this will inevitably lead to awakening of pure evil in their code. They should ideally learn about globals only after they are experienced enough to be able to tame them.

Comment: thanks a lot. i appreciate for your help